# Replace observation's value from one dataset if the observation is (is not) in the other one

Tags: python, pandas

I have one initial dataset, `df`, which includes the following data

```
         N        T  IND_N  IND_T
0     John     Mark      1      0
1     Mike     John      2      1
2  Stephan    Simon      1      0
3    Laura  Stephan      1      1
4     Matt    Simon      3      0
5    Simon     Joey      0      2
```

`N`=source, `T`=target, `IND_N` is the indicator assigned to the source, `IND_T` is the indicator assigned to the target.
I had split the dataset then in two small datasets, let's say (the split is made randomly)

`df1`

```
         N      T  IND_N  IND_T
0     John   Mark      1      0
1  Stephan  Simon      1      0
2    Simon   Joey      0      2
```

df2 (please note that, after splitting, I assigned a dummy value -1 to all the indicators in df2)

```
       N        T  IND_N  IND_T
0  Laura  Stephan     -1     -1
1   Matt    Simon     -1     -1
2   Mike     John     -1     -1
```

Now I would like to merge again the two datasets, but checking that there are no inconsistencies between indicators. In case the observation under `N` or `T` in `df2` dataset is also in `df1`, then I should assign to that observation its original indicator (i.e., from df1).

My expected output would be

`df_out`

```
         N        T  IND_N  IND_T
0     John     Mark      1      0
1  Stephan    Simon      1      0
2    Simon     Joey      0      2
3    Laura  Stephan     -1      1
4     Matt    Simon     -1      0
5     Mike     John     -1     -1
```

Stephan and Simon had -1 in df2 but, since they are also in df1, their indicators have been switched to their original value again.
*At the end, after the split, I would need to assign the dummy value -1 to the observation in N and T that are in df2 but not in df1.*

My approach would be

- check first the values of the indicators between the datasets I was thinking of using `isin` to check the values between the two datasets
- then assign the labels (from df1) for those observations (under N or T) in df2 that are also in df1
- use an if-statement plus logic (OR) value to consider all the cases (i.e., for N and T)
- finally, merge the two datasets.

I am having some problems to apply the first three bullets above. In particular, with checking the values. The below statement does not work

```
if df2.assign(df2=df2.N.isin(df1.N).astype(int))or df2.assign(df2=df2.T.isin(df1.T).astype(int)):
```

Can you please provide some help?

EDIT: I think that, after splitting the dataset in df1 and df2, to assign a dummy variable to observation' indicator (only of observations that are not in df1) could be also used a join... Probably it could be an easier way to approach the problem.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear. You have df1 and df2 and you want to merge them. In what situation do you change IND_N and IND_T?

Comment: After splitting the dataset in two datasets (df1 and df2), I keep indicators in df1 and I remove indicators (I actually assign to them a dummy value -1) from data in df2. However, since there could be source/target nodes in df2 (with dummy indicator -1) that are also in df1 (with original indicators), I would need to replace the dummy indicators of those cases with the original indicators that are in df1 (otherwise I will have a case with -1 in df2 and 2, for example, in df1, after merge).In short,only the observations that are in df2 but not in df1 should have their indicator replaced with -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

`df`

```
         N        T  IND_N  IND_T
0     John     Mark      1      0
1     Mike     John      2      1
2  Stephan    Simon      1      0
3    Laura  Stephan      1      1
4     Matt    Simon      3      0
5    Simon     Joey      0      2
```

`df1`

```
         N      T  IND_N  IND_T
0     John   Mark      1      0
1  Stephan  Simon      1      0
2    Simon   Joey      0      2
```

`df2`

```
       N        T  IND_N  IND_T
0  Laura  Stephan     -1     -1
1   Matt    Simon     -1     -1
2   Mike     John     -1     -1
```

Doing:
[`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
# For each column pair...
for values in (['T', 'IND_T'], ['N', 'IND_N']):
    col, _ = values
    
    # Make a new frame with just those values
    # and set the index.
    temp = df2[values].set_index(col)
    
    # Use pd.DataFrame.update to update your temp
    # frame with the non-modified frame.
    temp.update(df1[values].set_index(col))
    
    # Set the index for the main frame, 
    # update, and reset the index again.
    df = df.set_index(col)
    df.update(temp)
    df = df.reset_index()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         N        T  IND_N  IND_T
0     John     Mark    1.0    0.0
1     Mike     John   -1.0   -1.0
2  Stephan    Simon    1.0    0.0
3    Laura  Stephan   -1.0   -1.0
4     Matt    Simon   -1.0    0.0
5    Simon     Joey    0.0    2.0
```